# How to load pixel from one image in another

Tags: java, imagej

I'm new to Java and ImageJ and I'm trying to write a PluginFilter with ImageJ and Java. I want it to crop the right and left side of an image (500 pixel each), turn those parts 90 degrees to the outside and load them in a new image.

I already tried couple of options and now I got totally confused. I don't think there is any mistake in the algorith itself, but in the handling of ImageProcessor etc..

```
import ij.*;
import ij.process.*;
import ij.gui.*;
import java.awt.*;
import ij.plugin.filter.*;

public class Cropping28_Plugin implements PlugInFilter {
    ImagePlus imp;
    public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp){
        imp = IJ.getImage();    
        this.imp = imp;
            return DOES_ALL;
}
    public void run(ImageProcessor ip){
          //  int[] p = null;
          // int[] q = null;
            int height = imp.getHeight();
        int width = imp.getWidth();
             // New Image
          ImagePlus new_image = IJ.createImage("Nr1", "RGB", height, 500, 1); 

// turning the picture for y=0:500 (left side of picture)
            for(int x = 0; x < height; x++){
                for(int y = 0; y < 500; y++){
                    int k = 0;
// loading pixel
                    int q = imp.getProcessor().getPixel(x, y);
                    int [] convert = {q, q, q};
// pixel in newimage
                    int a = height - k;
                    int b = x;
                    new_image.getProcessor().putPixel(a, b, convert);
                    k++;

}
}
// turning the picture for y=get.Length:get.Length-500 (right side of picture)
            for(int x = 0; x < height; x++){
                for(int y = width -500; y < width; y++){
                    int k = 0;
// loading pixel
                    int q = imp.getProcessor().getPixel(x, y);
                    int [] convert = {q, q, q};
// pixel in new image
                    int a = height - k;
                    int b = x;
                    new_image.getProcessor().putPixel(a, b, convert);
                    k++;

}
}
// draw new picture
    new_image.show();
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be a picture containing the pixel of the right and left edge of the original image. The actual output is a write image of the size I expect. 
It would be awesome if someone had an idea!

Comment: In your code, `k` is always `0` when you evaluate `height - k`. What's the reason you're writing a plugin? This can probably be achieved in less than 10 lines of macro/script code. Also, consider asking questions like this one on http://forum.imagej.sc, there are many more ImageJ experts around.

Comment: because I simply didn't know about Macros. Thanks a lot, writing a macro was so much easier!